# nhibernate advice on session building

Tags: nhibernate, session, sessionfactory

I got big problem cuz i'm not so experienced with nhibernate and i need to choose best session solution to project so here is example of session usage:

-Session opens and make query to fill gridview
-Person double click on filled gridview and is redirected to another page with edit option
-He edit Object that he had from gridview
-He save object and go back to gridview
-Gridview is displaing saved object
-he edit another ....

So what is best session for me and when to open / close new sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a [session per request](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions?_sscc=t) (here's [one resource](http://ayende.com/blog/4117/nhibernate-unit-of-work-multiple-reuqests), google would find many more).
The scenario you've described is pretty commonplace; i'd use a `QueryOver` to populate your gridview, and `Load` to fetch the selected item. Simple.